# How to print String Value on iphone6.0 Simulator from JSON received data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I am receiving these data from my server -:

```
2014-06-04 13:58:40.201 myRequest[2349:11303]   parsing JSON: {
    "is_vip" = 1;
    "my_balance" = "1000.21";
    "my_name" = "my_foo";
    "my_num" = 100;
}
```

All valuees are printing well.

But when I am printing string value on my simulator  i am getting this error.

```
2014-06-04 13:58:51.967 myRequest[2349:11303] -[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8965530
2014-06-04 13:58:51.967 myRequest[2349:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8965530'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8f012 0x10cce7e 0x1d1a4bd 0x1c7ebbc 0x1c7e94e 0x3914 0xbd05c8 0xb3802a 0xb05d23 0xb05a34 0xb92301 0x49ed53f 0x49ff014 0x49ef7d5 0x1c35af5 0x1c34f44 0x1c34e1b 0x1be97e3 0x1be9668 0x1465c 0x295d 0x2885)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

printing code in XCODE -:

```
 NSLog(@"checking Apache value %@",[[greeting objectForKey:@"is_vip"] stringValue]);
```

and

```
self.ram.text = [[greeting objectForKey:@"my_name"] stringValue];
```

Comment: can you show your code here?

Comment: How to print the string value. Can you show code of it?

Comment: sir, i have edited and pasted in in last section

Comment: variable is_vip is working well but my_name is throwing error

Comment: If you see your JSON actually it is numeric value as it is not covered in double quotes, so you can access it using integerValue e.g. [[greeting objectForKey:@"is_vip"] integerValue] and give %d in NSLog

Comment: sir, problem is for string value not for integer..

Comment: Now does the error message tell you more? __NSCFString means your thing was a string already. This should help for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your NSLOg by below way.

```
NSLog(@"checking Apache value %@",[[greeting objectForKey:@"is_vip"] boolValue]);
```

For second line:

```
self.ram.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"my_name"];
```

Comment: i am implementing ...please wait

Comment: 2014-06-04 14:19:11.550 myRequest[2523:11303] -[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dc095c
2014-06-04 14:19:11.586 myRequest[2523:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dc095c'
*** First throw call stack: